Having trouble placing textures on my vehicle
I am new to 3d modeling, I recently purchased a model online and now I'm trying to convert it for a game. The problem I am having is that every time I place a texture on a separated part like for instance the bumper and then when I go attach the texture to it, then suddenly texturizes the cab of the vehicle which I didn't intend on doing. I also have an issue where I go to select a texture for the vehicle it doesn't show or make any change.

you need to assign the different materials to the faces you want

I’m voting to close this question because this topic is covered thoroughly in the Blender manual page on material assignment. I would just be copy-pasting or at best rewording portions of it in order to answer this question without further specifics on the situation, and that feels wrong.
